# Editable DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a program where I need the user to input data in a DataGrid.  I though the simple act of setting the 'CanUserAddRows' would be enough to let the user add new rows, but it seem that it won't cut it.

Is there something else I need to define to make them work? My DataGrid has ComboBoxes and TextBoxes in them so it's pretty common controls.

The code I have so far is this

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="GridFournisseur" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
     Margin="423,41,23.5,0" Height="193" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
     CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" IsTabStop="True" RowHeight="12"                         SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader">

    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>

        <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Fournisseur" Width="*" MinWidth="150"                                                
                                       IsReadOnly="False" />

        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Prix" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="50"
                                       Binding="{Binding Categorie}" 
                                       IsReadOnly="False"/>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Délai" Width="SizeToHeader" MinWidth="50"
                                       Binding="{Binding NoPiece}" 
                                       IsReadOnly="False"/>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

I just have this DataGrid in which I would like to edit its content and at the beginning it's empty.

Comment: Is your 'ItemsSource' set to an ObservableCollection<T>?

Comment: For the moment, I don't have ItemSource (might be the problem...) 
In this program, I would normally put an itemSource as a List(Of Something) but if I need to put something else then by all mean I will.

Comment: Maybe I'm not doing it right. What I would like to do is have the same thing as in a normal Windows Form application. Meaning having a datagrid in which a 'new row' is always visible for me to add data in it. I could also want to delete a row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be any of a number of things. Please take a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20081004043732/http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx).

The problem is most likely that you are binding to a collection view that does not support adding items. I believe that the grid might be expecting a collection view that implements [IEditableCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview.aspx) or [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx), interfaces that support adding items.

Answer (score 1):

`CanUserAddRows` is the correct property. Perhaps share some sample code.